# How can I prevent multiple selection of same value?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to prevent multiple selections of same value in my project.

My form [image]

```html
<div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <select name="number" class="form-control" id="index0">
                    <option value="">Select Number</option>
                    <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="addNumber" onclick="addNumber();">Add Number</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <select name="letter" class="form-control" id="index00">
                    <option value="">Select Letter</option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addLetter();">Add Letter</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="newHtml">
            <div class="newLetter">
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have two select box one for number and one for letter.

A number can have many letters eg, number 1 can have letters A,B,C,D,E, etc and same goes for other numbers.

When I append new form clicking add number button the selected number should not display there. And if for number 1 letter A is already selected then A should not appear for that number 1 if I click add letter button.
How to achieve that?

Comment: Sorry, but it's absolutely unclear what's the goal..

Comment: I think the best solution is to implement the logic in JS,hold arrays,numbers and letter and add logic in OnClick function, even better - use framework like angular / react / vue for 2 way binding

Comment: Maybe you can define a global variable which contains an array of what number has what letters. Then when ever one letter selected, that letter should be removed from array.

Answer (score 1):

Is this something like you want to achieve?

```js
let records = [];

const numberDropdown = document.querySelector("#dropdown-number"),
  letterDropdown = document.querySelector("#dropdown-letter"),
  submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-btn");

submitButton.addEventListener("click", handleEntry);
numberDropdown.addEventListener("change", updateDropdowns);
letterDropdown.addEventListener("change", updateDropdowns);

function handleEntry() {
  let selectedNumber = numberDropdown.value,
    selectedLetter = letterDropdown.value;
  records.push({
    number: selectedNumber,
    letter: selectedLetter
  });
  updateList();
  updateDropdowns();
  let i = 0;
  while (letterDropdown.options[i].disabled) {
    i++
  };
  letterDropdown.selectedIndex = i;
}

function updateDropdowns() {
  if (records.length) {
    let noLeft = true;
    document.querySelectorAll("#dropdown-letter option").forEach((option) => {
      let taken = false;
      records.forEach((record) => {
        if (
          option.value == record.letter &&
          numberDropdown.value == record.number
        ) {
          taken = true;
        }
      });
      if (taken) {
        option.disabled = true;
      } else {
        option.disabled = false;
        noLeft = false;
      }
    });
    if (noLeft) {
      submitButton.disabled = true;
      alert('select another number');
    } else {
      submitButton.disabled = false;
    }
  } else {
    document.querySelectorAll("#number-dropdown option").forEach((option) => {
      option.disabled = false;
    });
  }
}

updateDropdowns();
updateList();

function updateList() {
  document.querySelector('#list').innerHTML = '';
  records.forEach((record) => {
    document.querySelector('#list').innerHTML += `<li>${record.letter} | ${record.number}</li>`
  });
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown-number">
  <option value="0" selected>0</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="dropdown-letter">
  <option value="a">a</option>
  <option value="b">b</option>
  <option value="c">c</option>
  <option value="d">d</option>
</select>
<button id="submit-btn">Add</button>

<p>Entries:</p>
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: But there is also another dropdown which contains letter

Comment: @bsam020 is this better now?

Comment: this is what I want. Thank you Bouvanni.

Comment: but when I append the id attribute doesn't work? What can I do for id to work for appended html

Comment: Do you mean, you can't add an `id` to new elements in `ul`?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it's not so much hard with jQuery/CSS selectors. Try that one:

```
let letters = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

function addNumber() {
    let val1 = $("#index0").val();
    let val2 = $("#index00").val();
    if ($(".newLetter > .number[data-value=" + val1 + "]").length == 0) {
        $(".newLetter").append(
            '<div data-value="' + val1 + '" class="number">' + val1 + "</div>"
        );
        $('#index0 > option[value="' + val1 + '"]').remove();
        $('#index00 > option[value="' + letters[parseInt(val1) - 1] + '"]').remove();
    }
}

function addLetter() {
    let val1 = $("#index0").val();
    let val2 = $("#index00").val();
    if ($(".newLetter > .letter[data-value=" + val2 + "]").length == 0) {
        $(".newLetter").append(
            '<div data-value="' + val2 + '" class="letter">' + val2 + "</div>"
        );
        $('#index1 > option[value="' + val2 + '"]').remove();
    }
}
```

Look at it on [codepen](https://codepen.io/sundowatch/pen/ZEBbaev)

You should create an array, so can integrate the values. I may not understand correctly.

Comment: If A is selected for number 1 then A should not appear for number 1 but for other numbers it can be there in dropdown

Comment: @bsam020 updated the answer, take a look at it

Comment: Or if you want to validate two select inputs, then there should be only one button

Comment: there is not anything about validation. may be I am not explaining well